# Alg Geom - Generators of a Ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field (assume characteristic zero if you like.) Consider the set $S$ in $K^3$ parametrised by $(X,Y,Z)=(t^3,t^4,t^5)$. We see that $S$ is the simultaneous zero set of the ideal $I=(X^3−YZ,Y^2−XZ,Z^2−X^2Y):=(f,g,h).$

How can I show that $I$ cannot be generated by 2 elements? I think it might be useful to note that:
1. $I$ is prime.
2. $f,g,h$ are linearly independent over $K$.
3. $f,g,h$ are all irreducible.

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104491/curve-in-mathbba3-that-cannot-be-defined-by-2-equations

Comment: @Mariano Could you tell which program you used to plot those curves in the linked post? Thanks!

Comment: @FredrikMeyer, Mathematica